# query in model stops working after being changed

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have this working CI model function `get_info`:

```
function get_info($item_id)
{  

    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('item_id', $item_id);


    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {

        $item_obj=new stdClass();
        $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items_tier_prices');

        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $item_obj->$field='';
        }

        return $item_obj;
    }
}
```

I needed to modify above function `get_info` with this custom query:

```
function get_info($item_id)
{
$sql_query = $this->db->query("select * from (select items.name as name, items.category as category, items.supplier_id as supplier_id, items.item_number as item_number, items.product_id as product_id, items.description as description, items.size as size, items.tax_included as tax_included, items.cost_price as cost_price, items_tier_prices.unit_price  as unit_price, items.promo_price as promo_price, items.start_date as start_date, items.end_date as end_date, items.reorder_level as reorder_level, items.item_id as item_id, items.allow_alt_description as allow_alt_description, items.is_serialized as is_serialized, items.image_id as image_id, items.override_default_tax as override_default_tax, items.is_service as is_service, items.deleted as deleted

    from items
LEFT JOIN items_tier_prices
ON items.item_id=items_tier_prices.item_id
LEFT JOIN price_tiers
ON price_tiers.id=items_tier_prices.tier_id
where
 price_tiers.name='jendela kaca mati single'
 and items.deleted=0

 union
select items.*
from items
left join items_tier_prices
ON items.item_id=items_tier_prices.item_id
where items_tier_prices.item_id is null
and items.deleted=0
) x
where x.item_id=".$item_id);


$query = $this->db->query($sql_query);

if($query->num_rows()==1)
{
    return $query->row();
}
else
{
    $item_obj=new stdClass();

    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('price_tiers');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items_tier_prices'); 

  foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $item_obj->$field='';
    }

    return $item_obj;
}

}
```

The problem is after modifying the query and the list_field the function `get_info` doesn't work anymore.

I am SURE that the query works in phpmyadmin and that the query result produced in the function is the SAME. It produces the same column name and only 1 row of result.

But i am not sure with:

```
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('price_tiers');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items_tier_prices');
```

What's wrong with my modifications to stop the function `get_info` to work?

Comment: With a UNION, both queries must return the same number of columns and the columns from query 1 must be of the same data type as columns from query2

Comment: i am sure they have the same data. can u check the part of $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('price_tiers');
    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items_tier_prices');  is it right to put 3 tables on this? but i think i join them all so i have to list_field of all table

Comment: Also you are overwriting your variable. Try this:
`$fields = [];
$fields[] = $this->db->list_fields('items');
...`

Answer (score 0):

you are calling  `$this->db->query` twice.

change your code where you write your query to something like:

```
$sql_query = "select * from (select items.name as name
             ..etc..";
```

then execute the query as in your script:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql_query);
```

if your query is correct, you get one row returned. Keep in mind to handle exceptions where the query eventually returns 0 rows or more than 1 row.

You can also check your browser console. If there is an error in your query syntax, you'll find a `500 Internal Server Error` and it allows you to check what might have caused the error.